# How to determine the position of the third node from the position of the two nodes？

Tags: nodes, line, frame

Here is the image my existing code produces：
[image: 1]
I hope that the FFFFF of the rhombus can be directly above C and directly to the right of E. How should I do it? Below is my minimal working case：

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{siunitx} %SI单位
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[rectangle,draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (A) {
    A};
    \node[rectangle,draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (B) [below=of A]{B};
    \node[rectangle,draw=red, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (C) [right=of B]{C};
    \node[rectangle,draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (D) [right=of C]{D};
    \node[rectangle,draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (E) [above=of D] {E};
    \node[diamond,draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (F) [above=of C] {FFFFFfF};
    
        %Lines
    \draw[->] (A) -> (B);
    \draw[->] (B) -> (C);
    \draw[->] (C) -> (D);
    \draw[->] (D) -> (E);
    \draw[->] (E) -> (F);
    \draw[->] (F) -> (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And what I finally hope to get is this, that is, I need to add a very large dotted frame. How should this be realized?
[image: 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the option `on grid=true`, which will use the node centers (instead of their borders) for positioning. But then you will need to increase `node distance`.

For the dashed box, I suggest using the `fit` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{siunitx} %SI单位
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[on grid=true, node distance=3cm]
    
    \node[rectangle,draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (A) {
    A};
    \node[rectangle,draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (B) [below=of A]{B};
    \node[rectangle,draw=red, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (C) [right=of B]{C};
    \node[rectangle,draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (D) [right=of C]{D};
    \node[rectangle,draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (E) [above=of D] {E};
    \node[diamond,draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm] (F) [above=of C] {FFFFFfF};
    
        %Lines
    \draw[->] (A) -> (B);
    \draw[->] (B) -> (C);
    \draw[->] (C) -> (D);
    \draw[->] (D) -> (E);
    \draw[->] (E) -> (F);
    \draw[->] (F) -> (C);
    \node[draw, dashed, fit = {(B)(D)}, text height=2cm]{for $i=1,2,\dots,N$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can first define nodes and edges style in `tikzpicture` options and than write short code of image.
- Dashed rectangle is drawn as node, which fit around nodes B ... D:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,  % new
                fit,          % new
                positioning,
                shapes}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[% nodes, edges styles
node distance = 10mm and 10mm,
D/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.3, 
            inner xsep=0mm, draw, thick}, 
F/.style = {draw, dashed, inner ysep=3ex, yshift=-1ex,
            fit=#1},
N/.style = {draw=#1, thick, minimum size=10mm},
N/.default = black,
every edge/.append style = {draw, -Straight Barb}
                      ]
\node (A) [N]               {A};
\node (B) [N, below=of A]   {B};
\node (C) [N=red, 
              right=of B]   {C};
\node (D) [N, right=of C]   {D};
\node (E) [N, above=of D]   {E};
\path (E) -- node (F) [D] {FFFFFfF} (A);    % <---
% dashed rectangle
\node[F=(B) (D), 
      label={[anchor=south]below:{for $i=1,2,\dotsc,N$}}] {};
% arrows
\draw   (A) edge (B) 
        (B) edge (C)
        (C) edge (D) 
        (D) edge (E) 
        (E) edge (F) 
        (F) edge (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can place the node F at [the intersection](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.perpendicular) of a vertical line through `C` and a horizontal line through `A` or `E`:

```
\node[diamond] (F) at (C|-E) {FFFFFfF};
```

---

With the `calc` library you can place it halfway between (the centers) `A` and `E`:

```
\node[diamnond] (F) at ($(A)!.5!(E)$) {FFFFFfF};
```

or halfway between the borders of `A` and `E` with a node along a path:

```
\path (A) -- node[diamond] (F) {FFFFFfF} (E);
```

Though, in the latter you could also use `A.center` and `E.center` and in the former you could use `($(A.east)!.5!(E.west)$)` but since your nodes `A` and `E` have the same width there's no different between placing a node halfway between their centeres and halfway between their borders.

Of course, in all these cases, the [`node distance`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/node:distance) will not observed anymore but for the `F` node it was already too late for that.

---

You can use the [`on grid` option](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/on:grid) of the `positioning` library so that it measures the node distance between the nodes' centers which needs you to carefully set an appropriate node distance. (→ [Sandy G's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678708/16595))

---

You can place the nodes in a `matrix of nodes` which will place them on a grid but will make sure a minimum node distance is observed between them represented by `row sep` and `column sep`. By using the keyword [`between origins`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices#sec-20.3.2) in `row sep` and/or `column sep` a similar positioning algorithm as the `on grid` option can be used for the matrix.

```
\matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=1cm,
  column sep=1cm,
  cells={nodes={draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm}}]{
|(A)| A & |[diamond]  (F)| FFFFFfF & |(E)| E \\
|(B)| B & |[draw=red] (C)| C       & |(D)| D \\};
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, graphs, matrix, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[nodes={draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm}]
\node           (A)              {A};
\node           (B) [below=of A] {B};
\node[draw=red] (C) [right=of B] {C};
\node           (D) [right=of C] {D};
\node           (E) [above=of D] {E};
\node[diamond]  (F) at (C|-E)    {FFFFFfF};
% with calc
% \node[diamnond]  (F) at ($(A)!.5!(E)$) {FFFFFfF};
% or without
% \path (A) -- node[diamond] (F) {FFFFFfF} (E);
\end{scope}
\graph[path, ->, use existing nodes] {A, B, C, D, E, F -> C};

\node[
  fit={(B)(D)([yshift=+-1em]C.south)}, dashed, inner sep=+.5em, thick, draw,
  label={[above, inner sep=+.2em]south:for $i = 1, 2, \dots, N$}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=1cm,
  column sep=1cm,
  cells={nodes={draw, very thick, minimum size=10mm}}]{
|(A)| A & |[diamond]  (F)| FFFFFfF & |(E)| E \\
|(B)| B & |[draw=red] (C)| C       & |(D)| D \\};
\graph[path, ->, use existing nodes] {A, B, C, D, E, F -> C};

\node[
  fit={(B)(D)([yshift=+-1em]C.south)}, dashed, inner sep=+.5em, thick, draw,
  label={[above, inner sep=+.2em]south:for $i = 1, 2, \dots, N$}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]